# Why does ssh that has worked for months suddenly just hang and then connection refused?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I have an `ssh` `config` that I've been using for months.  the config is set up like this:

```
Host <hostname>
    Hostname <ip address in config>
    User <username>
    Identityfile /Users/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa
    ForwardAgent
```

And it has always worked just by doing `ssh <hostname>`.  Suddenly it times out today with this in verbose output:

```
ssh -vv <hostname>
OpenSSH_7.3p1, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/usernamei/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/usernamei/.ssh/config line 10: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/usernamei/.ssh/config line 56: Applying options for <hostname>
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "<ip address>" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <ip address> [<ip address>] port 22.
debug1: connect to address <ip address> port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host <ip address> port 22: Connection refused
```

i'm on a `macOSX`.  I am not even able to ping the address in my config:

```
ping <ip address in config>
```

...the above command times out....

I cannot figure out anything wrong with what I'm doing.  Can someone please help me?  What could be the possible cause?

Comment: do you have any control over destination host? it looks like network connectivity problem. did destination host or your network configuration changed?

Comment: neither changed AFAICT.  Is there a way to diagnose which one that is?  (i.e. the host or the configuration?)

Answer (score 1):

`Connection refused` means that your destination host is available, but is not running an `sshd` daemon to accept your connection.  Check with the sysadmin of that host.

The inability to `ping` a host has been meaningless for many many years.  I don't know why people still consider that an issue.

Comment: +1 about the inability  to `ping` a host.  Why do so many people suggest it as a valid method for diagnosis?